# send custom mail with variable via script

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, email-templates, custom

I want to send new register customer email with one variable generated by script.

I am trying using `$customerObj->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed');` Please tell

How I can send custom email template with variable?

I have created one custom email template `'new register email'` in transactional emails with `{{var myvar}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More or less a few arrays to setup, I would suggest tacking onto an observer event (or a core rewrite, in which case you'll find the send function for customer registrations in the mage core customer folder!) to send your custom script out (there's a list of the observers available if you google!):

Declare the sender as an array:

```
$sender = Array('name'  => 'You',
        'email' => 'you@domain.com');
```

The recipient address, just literally needs to be a string, similarly to the mail subject.

```
$email = 'customer@customer.com';
```

Set your template id:

```
$templateId = 40;
```

And finally declare your custom variables to be sent along to the template:

```
$vars = Array('nameOfCustomer' => $customerName,
              'shippingDetails' => $shipping,
              'storeName' => $store_name,
              'storeURL' => $store_url,
              'orderId' => $orderId);
```

Followed up with the send function, i tend to just leave the $name as a null var:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)
->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars, $storeId);
```

Then in your template call the var as literal for example:

```
{{var storeName}}
```