# send user and admin email for free shipping method

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, shipping, email, shipping-methods

i want to create email method. if customer select free shipping method  then admin and user both will get an  custom email.

how to do that?  need help.

there are two shipping . one is paid and second is free.  if customer select free  shipping method and place the order then admin and  customer both  will get email notification.

need help how to do that?

in module folder Custom_shipping.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
     <modules>
       <Custom_Shipping>
         <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>

        </Custom_Shipping>
      </modules>
  </config>
```

in Model Folder Observer.php

```
   <?php

   class Custom_Shipping_Model_Observer(){

    public function salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore($observer)
    {

    $shipment = $observer->getShipment();
    $order = $shipment->getOrder();
    $storeId = $order->getStore()->getStoreId();

     die('test');


     }


}
```

ann etc/config.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
   <modules>
    <Custom_Shipping>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Custom_Shipping>
  </modules>
<global>
   <events>             
      <sales_order_shipment_save_before>
        <observers>
            <shipping>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>shipping/observer</class>
                <method>salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore</method>
            </shipping>
        </observers>
     </sales_order_shipment_save_before>
     </events>
     </global>
     </config>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: i don't know what is the issue. i created this module and unfortunately it is not working. i want to send email to user if user place place the order using freeshipping. as you suggested to use observer and sales_order_shipment_save_before  i just tried to create the observer but it isn't working. can you help me?

Comment: Is the code called? Is the file included? Does the module show up in the backend? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: yes . module show up in system >> configuration >> advanced. it is is enable. i don't know why it is not firing the action

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be you are missing the model definition in your config.xml so the observer does not get called.

You have two options.

Either update `<class>custom_shipping/observer</class>` to use `<class>Custom_Shipping_Model_Observer</class>`

Or create the following section in your config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <custom_shipping>
            <class>Custom_Shipping_Model</class>
        </custom_shipping>
    </models>
</global>
```

Thanks to Fabian for pointing out `<shipping>` is already in use :)

Comment: Don't use `shipping``, this is already used by Mage_Shipping :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt opps :)

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the event `sales_order_shipment_save_before` check wether the order has an ID, if no, check the method and if the method is `free`, then send an email.

Further informations:

- [How to send an email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/send-custom-mail-with-variable-via-script)
- [How to implement an observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4476/217)

Comment: what will be in overserver?

Comment: The check whether the shipment has an id (to check whether it is new and only send the mail once) and the mail sending

Comment: hi, i updated the question with the module i created. please have a look. i just created observer. but it is not working. need help